# Design crashed when use host name on IE?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-7, cross-browser

I have very strange  problem with IE, on development environment my design is looking perfect also working perfect in published environnment but only when i call it by server ip,

**for example:**

if write  `"http://10.0.0.13:700"` i in address bar (IE), my design is looking perfect.

if write  `"http://MyHostName"` i in address bar (IE), my design crashes.

Note that i face this problem only with IE.

Used technology as the following:

```
ASP.NET 3.5

IIS 7.0
```

Comment: without codes, hard to tell.

Comment: have you tried http://MyHostName:700 ?

Comment: whats the error message you get?

Comment: @hbrock yes i tried every thing.

Comment: @Dejan no error message, only the design is crached

Answer (score 0):

i found where is the problem, for some reason when you call your site by host name Browser 
Mode change to be Compatibility View.

my design is Not support IE 7 so the issue will appear with Compatibility View Mode.

so i solved this problem by change Browse Mode to IE9

Thanks you All.